# Simplifying text.replace() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can this code be written in a simplified manner?

```
text.replace('</p>','<br/>').replace('</P>','<br/>');
```

Comment: What happens to the opening `<p>`-tag? And: Your code replaces the first occurrence only. I do not think that this is what you need. And: HTML manipulation using its string representation? In JavaScript? Seriously? And: Its `<br />`, not `<br/>`!

Comment: this part of the code, <p> tag should be not replace

Comment: @Yosef: Wouldn't that result in invalid markup? Omitting a closing tag is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Yosef - then you are creating malformed HTML, which the browser will correct anyway when building the DOM.

Comment: @elusive @Kobi I think he is keeping the last closing tag by some condition =). So you get a lot of breaks and then the last closing tag again. Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Marnix - If I understand correctly: `<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>` --> `<p>1<br /><p>2<br /><p>3<br />`. Not too valid, even with another closing tag `:)`

Comment: @Kobi, ah indeed, that would be invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write:

```
text.replace(/<\/p>/ig,'<br/>');
```

- `/<\/p>/` is the regex, which matches the literal string. `/` is escaped because it is the regex delimiter in JavaScript.
- `/ig` are the regex flags - `i` for case-insensitive, and `g` for global, to replace more than the first `</p>`.

However, JavaScript has much better tools for dealing with the DOM structure, you can do better than manipulating raw source code. For example, using jQuery you can write:

```
$('p').replaceWith('<br />');
```

or:

```
$('p').after('<br />');
```

None of them may do what you need, but it is probably easier and more robust without sting manipulations.

Comment: @Yosef - Already there, even used a jQuery example. However, you need to explain better what you're trying to do `:)`

Comment: `$('p').replaceWith('<br />');` would replace the complete p and content with a breakline, right?

Comment: @Marnix - Correct! As I've said, it isn't too clear what the OP is aiming for here, this is just an example.